# How to Get Element By Class and add/remove attribute in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Below mentioned is the way to `get the element` by `Class Name`

```
var Tag = replaceContentInContainer('className');

function replaceContentInContainer(matchClass) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if ((" " + elems[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + matchClass + " ") > -1) {
        }
    }
}
```

I have `onclick` and `style` attribute with this Tag.

My query is, How can I remove/add the `onclick/style` attribute in this tag using `JavaScript` ?

Comment: Would you consider using JQuery for this task or you need only pure JS ?

Comment: why don't you use [jquery class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using JQuery you could use class selectors and then remove associated attributes by using the removeattr function:

```
$('.className').removeAttr('click style')
```

To add and remove some class:

```
$('.className').addClass('className').removeClass('newlyaddedClass')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually have to add the class like this '<a class="classname newlyaddedclass">Previous</a>' and remove 'newlyaddedclass' only.

Comment: In that case you can make use of `removeClass` method in jQuery.

Comment: removeClass('newlyaddedClass') and addClass('classname') is all you need on your selector.

Comment: Updated to reflect the comments.

Comment: How can I remove/add the onclick/style attribute in this tag using `JavaScript`? pure JS or jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 defines a method, getElementsByClassName(), that allows us to select sets of document elements based on the identifiers in their class attribute.

```
var elts = document.getElementsByClassName("className");

for(var e = 0; e < elts.length; e++) { // For each element
   var elt = elts[e];
   elt.removeAttribute("style");
   elt.removeAttribute("onclick");
}
```

**removeAttribute()**
removeAttribute() deletes a named attribute from this element. Attempts to remove non- existent attributes are silently ignored.

**setAttribute()**
This method sets the specified attribute to the specified value. If no attribute by that name already exists, a new one is created.

**hasAttribute()**
This method returns true if this element has an attribute with the specified name and false
otherwise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeAttribute

Comment: The question is based on removing attributes of an element and not selecting elements... Please read questions before posting a solution

Comment: ok, there are mothods that can delete and set attributes without using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
​$(function(){
    $(".className").removeAttr("onclick style");       
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/h6CT9/

Comment: There is no need to use the loop. `$('className').removeAttr('onclick style')` is enough.

Comment: Considering your solution this is more better and efficient.  It was just an update from your JSfiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/h6CT9/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
var Tag = replaceContentInContainer('className');
for(var i = 0; i < Tag.length; i++){
   Tag[i].removeAttribute('onclick');
   Tag[i].removeAttribute('style');
}
```

## update

I'm sorry, i saw your code incorrectly. I assumed your function was returning an array of elements with that classname... so, using your function:

```
function replaceContentInContainer(matchClass) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;
    for (i in elems) {
        if ((" " + elems[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + matchClass + " ") > -1) {
           elems[i].removeAttribute('onclick');
           elems[i].removeAttribute('style');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. You can check ur side. not showing any `length` in line `r(var i = 0; i < Tag.length; i++){`

Comment: no, that would be with jQuery. JavaScript is removeAttribute()